# Convolution of two characteristic functions

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics, distribution-theory, convolution

Given two intervals on XY-plane: $I_1$
lying on OX-axis, $I_2$
lying on OY-axis. Compute convolution of two characteristic functions of these intervals.

$$\chi_{I_1} \ast \chi_{I_2}.$$

MY ATTEMPT:

$(\chi_{I_1},w)=\int_{I_1}w(0,x)dx,$

$(\chi_{I_2},w)=\int_{I_2}w(0,x)dx,$

$(\chi_{I_1}\ast \chi_{I_2},w)=(\chi_{I_1},  (\chi_{I_2},w))=\int_{I_1}\int_{I_2}w  dy_1  dx_2 =(\chi_{I_2\times I_1},w).$

Comment: In order to convolve two functions they have to be defined on the same space, $\mathbb{R}^2$ in OP case. I guess the proper definition of  the functions should be $f_1=\chi_{I_1\times \mathbb{R}}$ and $f_2=\chi_{ \mathbb{R}\times I_2}.$